# Pig-English Translate Program Displaying Incorrectly

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program where English is transformed into Pig English.
All working fine at the moment except where I'm searching for the consonant at the first letter, second letter or third letter to find the next vowel, then move those consonants at the back of the word and add "ay".

As shown in the below output example, this code recognises that 'e' is a vowel in the second letter of the word 'remember', and changes it to 'emember-ray'.
Then, I try 'potato' hoping it recognises that 'o' is second letter of the word.
Weirdly it translates 'potato' to 'ato-potay' instead of 'otato-pay'
Any ideas why this happens? It has something to do with the else if statements in the for loop I'm sure.

Here is the code:

```
class Main {

    public static String engPig(String englishWord)
    {
        String pigWord = englishWord;

        String[] vowel = {
                "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"
        };
        String removeQAndU = "";
        String consonants = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < vowel.length; i++) {     
            if(pigWord.startsWith(vowel[i])) { // If the first letter of the word is a vowel then keep it the same and add -ay.
                pigWord = pigWord + "-ay";
            }
            else
            {
                if(pigWord.startsWith("qu")) {
                    removeQAndU = pigWord.substring(2); // Saves the rest of the word (starting at third letter - substring 2) in a variable. Substring index also starts at 0 for first letter, 1 for second letter etc. First two letters "qu" are now so far removed from the word.
                    pigWord = removeQAndU + "-quay"; // Then add quay at the end
                    break;
                }
                else if(!pigWord.startsWith(vowel[i])) {
                    if(pigWord.substring(1, 2).equals(vowel[i]) && !pigWord.substring(2, 3).equals(vowel[i])) {
                    consonants = pigWord.substring(0, 1);
                    pigWord = pigWord.substring(1) + "-" + consonants + "ay";
                    break;
                }
                else if(!pigWord.substring(1, 2).equals(vowel[i]) && pigWord.substring(2, 3).equals(vowel[i])) {
                    consonants = pigWord.substring(0, 2);
                    pigWord = pigWord.substring(2) + "-" + consonants + "ay";
                    break;
                }
                else if(!pigWord.substring(1, 2).equals(vowel[i]) && !pigWord.substring(2, 3).equals(vowel[i]) && pigWord.substring(3, 4).equals(vowel[i])) {
                    consonants = pigWord.substring(0, 3);
                    pigWord = pigWord.substring(3) + "-" + consonants + "ay";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //You will build pigWord using substrings of englishWord
    //Do not edit below this point
    return pigWord;
}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Computer Programming 1 Fall Final Program");
    PLS.run();
}
}
```

Output:

> Computer Programming 1 Fall Final Program
>   
> Welcome to the Pig Latin Translation Machine!
>   
> Enter sentence to translate(no punctuation): school
>   
> ool-schay
>   
> Would you like to translate another? y
>   
> Enter sentence to translate(no punctuation): remember
>   
> emember-ray
>   
> Would you like to translate another? y
>   
> Enter sentence to translate(no punctuation): potato
>   
> ato-potay
>   
> Would you like to translate another?

Answer (score 0):

In case of `Potato`, `!pigWord.substring(1, 2).equals(vowel[i]) && !pigWord.substring(2, 3).equals(vowel[i]) && pigWord.substring(3, 4).equals(vowel[i])` holds true.

You have `vowel` array as `{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}`. So, your loop begins with i = 0 and checks for `pigWord.startsWith(vowel[i])`. It is false.

So, it comes to the else condition.

Currently, `pigWord.substring(1, 2) = o`, `pigWord.substring(2, 3) = t`, `pigWord.substring(3, 4) = a` and `vowel[i] = a`. So, your third condition will hold true in these circumstances.

Edit:

A much simplified version of the `engPig` function can be this (Using Java 8 Stream):

```
public static String engPig(String englishWord)
{
    String pigWord = englishWord;
    String[] vowel = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"};

    if (pigWord.startsWith("qu")) {
        pigWord = pigWord.substring(2) + "-quay";
    } else {
        String pigWordLowerCase = pigWord.toLowerCase();

        Optional<Integer> firstIndex = Arrays.asList(vowel).stream()
                            .map(v -> pigWordLowerCase.indexOf(v))
                            .filter(val -> !val.equals(-1))
                            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a));

        if (firstIndex.isPresent()) {
            pigWord = pigWord.substring(firstIndex.get()) + "-" + pigWord.substring(0, firstIndex.get()) + "ay";
        }
    }

    return pigWord;
}
```